# Separate bootstrap classes with my own?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use bootstrap. Do I need separate rows with my own classes? Because if I don't I can't set the background of the section for example. Which piece of code is better?

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="row"></nav>
    <section class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          some text
      </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <nav></nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <section>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          some text
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Better for what? :-)

Comment: Better to use =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both and change background of section as you prefer. Just add your own class and set css.

```css
nav{
height:30px !important;
width:100%;
display:block;
background-color: red;
}

.containercolor{
background-color: black;
margin:0px;
}

.row{
margin: 0px !important;
}

.sectionrow{
height: 200px;
}

.colcolor{
background-color: green;
height:100%;
}

.sectionrow{
background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav>
</nav>

<div class="container-flex containercolor">
    <div class="row sectionrow">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 colcolor">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-flex ">
    <div class="row containercolor">
      <nav></nav>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <section class="sectionrow">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          some text
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
</div>
```